# jQuery - Remove active class if checkbox checked (multiple conditions)

Tags: jquery

I want to maintain having only one `.menu` `active` at a time so I set up the code to remove the active class of the last `.menu` that received the `active` class. I can't use `id` because I have multiple items each with their own unique id so I tried using `data-type` & `data-id` to call each unique set of buttons and menus.

How do I get the code to remove the last `active` class of a `.menu` when one of the other radio buttons are selected on each item? In other words give the `active` class to the `.menu` of it's corresponding button, but then remove it if another radio is checked or it is checked again (removing all `active` menu's).

```js
$('input[name="studio"]').change(function() {
  var t = $(this).closest(".item");
  var id = $(this).data("type");
  $(".menu[data-id=" + id + "]").toggleClass("active", this.checked);
  var menuCat = t.find(".menu--categories");
  var menuLoc = t.find(".menu--locations");
  var menuProj = t.find(".menu--projects");
  var btnCat = $(this).closest(".cat_label").find("input[id=" + id + "]");
  var btnLoc = $(this).closest(".loc_label").find("input[id=" + id + "]");
  var btnProj = $(this).closest(".proj_label").find("input[id=" + id + "]");

  if (btnCat.is(":checked") && $(this).attr("id") === btnLoc) {
    btnLoc.prop("checked", true);
    btnCat.prop("checked", false);
    btnProj.prop("checked", false);
    menuCat.removeClass("active");
  }
  if (btnCat.is(":checked") && $(this).attr("id") === btnProj) {
    btnProj.prop("checked", true);
    btnLoc.prop("checked", false);
    btnCat.prop("checked", false);
    menuCat.removeClass("active");
  }
  if (btnLoc.is(":checked") && $(this).attr("id") === btnCat) {
    btnCat.prop("checked", true);
    btnProj.prop("checked", false);
    btnLoc.prop("checked", false);
    menuLoc.removeClass("active");
  }
  if (btnLoc.is(":checked") && $(this).attr("id") === btnProj) {
    btnProj.prop("checked", true);
    btnCat.prop("checked", false);
    btnLoc.prop("checked", false);
    menuLoc.removeClass("active");
  }
  if (btnProj.is(":checked") && $(this).attr("id") === btnCat) {
    btnCat.prop("checked", true);
    btnProj.prop("checked", false);
    btnLoc.prop("checked", false);
    menuProj.removeClass("active");
  }
  if (btnProj.is(":checked") && $(this).attr("id") === btnLoc) {
    btnLoc.prop("checked", true);
    btnProj.prop("checked", false);
    btnCat.prop("checked", false);
    menuProj.removeClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  border: 2px solid
}

.menu {
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
  border: 1px solid
}

.active {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="menu menu--categories" data-id="cat"></div>
  <label class="cat_label" for="cat" data-btn="categories">
    <input id="cat" data-type="cat" type="radio" name="studio" />
    Categories
  </label>
  <div class="menu menu--locations" data-id="loc"></div>
  <label class="loc_label" for="loc" data-btn="locations">
    <input id="loc" data-type="loc" type="radio" name="studio" />
    Locations
  </label>
  <div class="menu menu--projects" data-id="proj"></div>
  <label class="proj_label" for="proj" data-btn="projects">
    <input id="proj" data-type="proj" type="radio" name="studio" />
    Projects
  </label>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="menu menu--categories" data-id="cat_2"></div>
  <label class="cat_label" for="cat_2" data-btn="categories">
    <input id="cat_2" data-type="cat_2" type="radio" name="studio" />
    Categories
  </label>
  <div class="menu menu--locations" data-id="loc_2"></div>
  <label class="loc_label" for="loc_2" data-btn="locations">
    <input id="loc_2" data-type="loc_2" type="radio" name="studio" />
    Locations
  </label>
  <div class="menu menu--projects" data-id="proj_2"></div>
  <label class="proj_label" for="proj_2" data-btn="projects">
    <input id="proj_2" data-type="proj_2" type="radio" name="studio" />
    Projects
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: get all elements with class "menu" in your javascript and every time you click on a radio button, loop through the "menus" removing the "active" class and then add that class to the specific element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Henrique mentioned above, removing the class on all items with class 'menu'.

```
$('input[name="studio"]').change(function() {
        $('.menu').removeClass('active'); // add this line
```